# How to whitelist multiple ip addresses to multiple different azure services?

Tags: azure, vpn, azure-virtual-network

Right now we have multiple resources like storage accounts and key vaults where the team is using the firewall setting within the networking tab on the individual services. This means when their ip changes after a disconnect/connect to the company VPN they have to go in to each service and add their new IP address.

Not being well versed in Azure networking possibilities, what are some of the options we have to allow a group of incoming IP addresses to be able to access all these services without having to individually touch each service to add their new ip address?

All services are also on the same virtual network.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I used to work on Azure Cloud services as a DevOps in the past.

There should be multiple ways to control incoming network traffic to your landing zone or azure resources. But you should consider your requirements meet the solution.

Here are few you could take a look at which I used:

```
Virtual network service endpoints
Azure Firewall
Network Security Groups
ExpressRoute
```